# Reversing a number using reverse for loop in Postgresql in PgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am Trying to reverse string, let's say '1234' using reverse for loop.
 But the output is coming as `<NULL>`

```
    DO $$
    DECLARE
    L_NO VARCHAR(5) := '1234';
    L_LEN NUMERIC(5);
    L_REV_NO VARCHAR(5);
    BEGIN
    L_LEN := CHAR_LENGTH(L_NO) ;
    RAISE NOTICE 'STRING LENGTH IS %' , L_LEN  ;
    FOR  CNTR IN  REVERSE  L_LEN..1 LOOP
   L_REV_NO = L_REV_NO||SUBSTRING(L_NO,CNTR,1);
    END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'NUMBER IS %' ,L_NO ;
    RAISE NOTICE 'REVERSE NUMBER IS %' ,L_REV_NO ;
    END $$ ;
```

---

### OUTPUT

```
NOTICE:  STRING LENGTH IS 4
NOTICE:  NUMBER IS 5484
NOTICE:  REVERSE NUMBER IS <NULL>
```

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong.??

Comment: Maybe just use `REVERSE` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/4979/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use: `L_REV_NO = L_REV_NO||SUBSTRING(L_NO,CNTR,1);` you do `L_REV_NO = NULL || ... => NULL`

You need to initialize `L_REV_NO` variable first:

```
 DO $$
    DECLARE
    L_NO VARCHAR(5) := '1234';
    L_LEN NUMERIC(5);
    L_REV_NO VARCHAR(5) = '';
    BEGIN
    L_LEN := CHAR_LENGTH(L_NO) ;
    RAISE NOTICE 'STRING LENGTH IS %' , L_LEN  ;
    FOR  CNTR IN  REVERSE  L_LEN..1 LOOP
   L_REV_NO = L_REV_NO||SUBSTRING(L_NO,CNTR,1);
    END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'NUMBER IS %' ,L_NO ;
    RAISE NOTICE 'REVERSE NUMBER IS %' ,L_REV_NO ;
    END $$ ;
```

---

Another simple solution is to use built-in [`REVERSE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) function.

```
SELECT REVERSE('1234')
-- 4321
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/4979/0)